# How to translate |= operator from JavaScript to Delphi ?

Tags: javascript, delphi

Today I faced an operator that I don't know what means in JavaScript, |= . Google doesn't help too much when you try to look for this "strange" characters. 
Someone knows what it means ? And How I convert it to Delphi ?

Thanks,

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment) always helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
a |= b;
```

It is equal to this

```
a = a | b;
```

The operator `|` is called the bitwise OR operator and it

> Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of
>   either or both operands are ones.

For further information regarding the bitwise operators in JavaScript, please have a look at [Mozilla's JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR).

According to [the Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators), I think that you are looking for the `or` operator:

```
a := a Or b;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is bitwise or.    In Delphi,

```
a := a or b;
```